# I'm trying to parse a JSON correctly with Python/Django

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, decode, encode

I'm trying to consume some data from a `JSON` with requests, but I consistently receive a Parsing error when I try to validate.

I try this code, transforming from `dict` to `string`, and later to `JSON`.

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('http://codehere.com', auth=('user', 'pass')).json()
json.loads(json.dumps(r))
print(r)
```

Before:

```
{
    "result": [
        "[
            {
                \"IDE_NOMBRE\":\"DUMMY\",
                \"IDE_CODIGO\":1,
                \"TER_IDENTIFICACION\":\"DUMMY\",
                \"TER_CIUEXPCED\":\"\",
                \"TER_DEPEXPCED_NOM\":\"\",
                \"TER_CIUEXPCED_NOM\":\"\",
                \"TER_FCHEXPCED\":null,
                \"TER_SEXO\":\"M\",
                \"TER_APELLIDO1\":\"DUMMY\",
                \"TER_APELLIDO2\":\"DUMMY\u00D1O\",
                \"TER_NOMBRE\":\"DUMMY\",
                \"TER_NOMBRE1\":\"\",
                \"TER_CUINACI\":\"\",
                \"TER_DEPNACI_NOM\":\"\",
                \"TER_CUINACI_NOM\":\"\",
                \"TER_FCHNACI\":null,
                \"TER_NROHIJOS\":0,
                \"ESTCIV_NOMBRE\":\"\",
                \"ESTCIV_CODIGO\":\"\",
                \"NIVESC_CODIGO\":\"\",
                \"NIVESC_NOMBRE\":\"\",
                \"TER_BARRIO\":\"\",
                \"CIU_CODIGO\":\"05001\",
                \"CIU_DEPTO\":\"DUMMY\",
                \"CIU_NOMBRE\":\"DUMMY\",
                \"TER_TELEFONO\":\"\",
                \"TER_EMAIL\":\"\",
                \"TER_DIRECCION\":\"\",
                \"TER_TELMOVIL\":\"\",
                \"TER_PERSONASCARGO\":0,
                \"TIPVIV_DESCRIPCION\":\"\",
                \"CLI_ESTRATO\":\"\",
                \"CLI_FCHAFILIACION\":\"2018-10-01 00:00:00\",
                \"CLI_CODISS\":\"\",
                \"ACT_CODIGO\":\"1\",
                \"ASESOR_WEB\":0,
                \"COD_CIIU\":\"\",
                \"TIPTRIB_CCN\":0,
                \"TIPTRIB_NOMBRE\":\"\",
                \"SECO_CODIGO\":\"\",
                \"SECO_NOMBRE\":\"\",
                \"BAN_CODIGO\":\"DUMMY\",
                \"BAN_NOMBRE\":\"DUMMY\",
                \"TER_TPOCNTA\":\"1\",
                \"TER_CUENTA\":\"DUMMY\",
                \"TER_TIPONATU\":\"N\",
                \"JORLAB_CODIGO\":\"\",
                \"JORLAB_NOMBRE\":\"\",
                \"OCU_CODIGO\":\"\",
                \"OCU_NOMBRE\":\"\",
                \"TPS_CCN\":\"1\",
                \"TPS_DESCRIPCION\":\"NORMAL\",
                \"OBSERVACIONES\":\"\",
                \"TER_TOTING\":0,
                \"TER_TOTEGRE\":0,
                \"TER_TOTACTIV\":0,
                \"TER_TOTPASIV\":0,
                \"TER_TOTPATRIM\":0,
                \"TER_TOTCOST\":0,
                \"CLI_MUJCABFAM\":\"\",
                \"AFECTA_VIVIENDA\":\"\",
                \"TER_ENVIOCORRESP\":\"\",
                \"COENT_CCN\":0,
                \"COENT_NOMBRE\":\"\",
                \"CLI_SALARIO\":0,
                \"CLI_OTRSEGRE\":0,
                \"CTR_CODIGO\":\"3\",
                \"CTR_NOMBRE\":\"DUMMY\",
                \"CLI_ULFCHLIQU\":null,
                \"PRO_CODTER\":0,
                \"PRO_NOMBRE\":\"\",
                \"PRO_NOMBRE_1\":\"DUMMY\",
                \"PRO_CODIGO\":7,
                \"TER_OTRING\":0,
                \"TER_CONOTRING\":\"\",
                \"TER_RELPERPEP\":\"\",
                \"TIPVIV_CCN\":0,
                \"CAR_NOMBRE\":\"\",
                \"NOM_CONY1\":\"\",
                \"NOM_CONY2\":\"\",
                \"APE_CONY1\":\"\",
                \"APE_CONY2\":\"\",
                \"DEP_CODDILI\":\"\",
                \"CIU_CODDILI\":\"\",
                \"TER_FCHDILI\":null,
                \"EMP_CODIGO\":\"E2\",
                \"EMP_NOMBRE\":\"DUMMY\",
                \"TER_EMPLAB\":\"\",
                \"TER_RELLAB\":\"\",
                \"CIU_EMPLAB\":\"\",
                \"CIU_NOMBRE_1\":\"DUMMY\",
                \"TER_DIREMPLAB\":\"\",
                \"TER_TELEMPLAB\":\"\",
                \"TER_CELEMPLAB\":\"\",
                \"TER_SUELDO\":0,
                \"TER_FCHINEMPLAB\":null,
                \"TER_FCHTERCONT\":null,
                \"TER_TIPCONTRA\":\"\",
                \"CTR_NOMBRE_1\":\"\",
                \"NRO_TARVISIO\":\"\",
                \"NRO_TARVISIO1\":\"\",
                \"PAI_PK\":0,
                \"PAI_NAC\":170,
                \"PAIS_CODIGO\":\"\",
                \"TER_AUTTRATDATOS\":\"\",
                \"TER_CCNASESOR\":0,
                \"CIIU_CODIGO_2\":\"\",
                \"CIIU_NOMBRE\":\"\",
                \"SECO_CODIGO_2\":\"\",
                \"SECO_NOMBRE_1\":\"\",
                \"TER_TOTEXCED\":0,
                \"TER_DIGITOVERIF\":\"\",
                \"VALORCOND\":0,
                \"TEL_CONY\":\"\",
                \"EMAIL_CONY\":\"\",
                \"NIVEL_EST_CONY\":\"\",
                \"ACTIVIDAD_CONY\":\"\",
                \"TER_SINANLUCR\":\"\",
                \"TER_SIGLA\":\"\",
                \"TIENSAL_CCODIGO\":0,
                \"TER_SOCIO_S_N\":\"S\",
                \"TER_TELEFONOLAB\":\"\",
                \"CIU_CODIGOLAB\":\"\",
                \"TER_DIRECCIONLAB\":\"\",
                \"COD_CIIU_1\":\"\",
                \"CIIU_NOMBRE_1\":\"\",
                \"TER_TOTCOSTOP\":0,
                \"ESTRATO_CONY\":\"\",
                \"TER_RAZONSOCIAL\":\"\",
                \"CLI_FCHINGRESOCIA\":null,
                \"TER_NOMCOMPLETO\":\"DUMMY DUMMY\u00D1O DUMMY\"
            }
        ]"
    ]
}
```

Results:

```
{'result': ['[
        {
            "IDE_NOMBRE": "",
            "IDE_CODIGO": 1,
            "TER_IDENTIFICACION": "",
            "TER_CIUEXPCED": "",
            "TER_DEPEXPCED_NOM": "",
            "TER_CIUEXPCED_NOM": "",
            "TER_FCHEXPCED": null,
            "TER_SEXO": "M",
            "TER_APELLIDO1": "",
            "TER_APELLIDO2": "",
            "TER_NOMBRE": "",
            "TER_NOMBRE1": "",
            "TER_CUINACI": "",
            "TER_DEPNACI_NOM": "",
            "TER_CUINACI_NOM": "",
            "TER_FCHNACI": null,
            "TER_NROHIJOS": 0,
            "ESTCIV_NOMBRE": "",
            "ESTCIV_CODIGO": "",
            "NIVESC_CODIGO": "",
            "NIVESC_NOMBRE": "",
            "TER_BARRIO": "",
            "CIU_CODIGO": "",
            "CIU_DEPTO": "",
            "CIU_NOMBRE": "",
            "TER_TELEFONO": "",
            "TER_EMAIL": "",
            "TER_DIRECCION": "",
            "TER_TELMOVIL": "",
            "TER_PERSONASCARGO": 0,
            "TIPVIV_DESCRIPCION": "",
            "CLI_ESTRATO": "",
            "CLI_FCHAFILIACION": "",
            "CLI_CODISS": "",
            "ACT_CODIGO": "",
            "ASESOR_WEB": 0,
            "COD_CIIU": "",
            "TIPTRIB_CCN": 0,
            "TIPTRIB_NOMBRE": "",
            "SECO_CODIGO": "",
            "SECO_NOMBRE": "",
            "BAN_CODIGO": "",
            "BAN_NOMBRE": "",
            "TER_TPOCNTA": "1",
            "TER_CUENTA": "",
            "TER_TIPONATU": "N",
            "JORLAB_CODIGO": "",
            "JORLAB_NOMBRE": "",
            "OCU_CODIGO": "",
            "OCU_NOMBRE": "",
            "TPS_CCN": "1",
            "TPS_DESCRIPCION": "",
            "OBSERVACIONES": "",
            "TER_TOTING": 0,
            "TER_TOTEGRE": 0,
            "TER_TOTACTIV": 0,
            "TER_TOTPASIV": 0,
            "TER_TOTPATRIM": 0,
            "TER_TOTCOST": 0,
            "CLI_MUJCABFAM": "",
            "AFECTA_VIVIENDA": "",
            "TER_ENVIOCORRESP": "",
            "COENT_CCN": 0,
            "COENT_NOMBRE": "",
            "CLI_SALARIO": 0,
            "CLI_OTRSEGRE": 0,
            "CTR_CODIGO": "",
            "CTR_NOMBRE": "",
            "CLI_ULFCHLIQU": null,
            "PRO_CODTER": 0,
            "PRO_NOMBRE": "",
            "PRO_NOMBRE_1": "",
            "PRO_CODIGO": 7,
            "TER_OTRING": 0,
            "TER_CONOTRING": "",
            "TER_RELPERPEP": "",
            "TIPVIV_CCN": 0,
            "CAR_NOMBRE": "",
            "NOM_CONY1": "",
            "NOM_CONY2": "",
            "APE_CONY1": "",
            "APE_CONY2": "",
            "DEP_CODDILI": "",
            "CIU_CODDILI": "",
            "TER_FCHDILI": null,
            "EMP_CODIGO": "",
            "EMP_NOMBRE": "",
            "TER_EMPLAB": "",
            "TER_RELLAB": "",
            "CIU_EMPLAB": "",
            "CIU_NOMBRE_1": "",
            "TER_DIREMPLAB": "",
            "TER_TELEMPLAB": "",
            "TER_CELEMPLAB": "",
            "TER_SUELDO": 0,
            "TER_FCHINEMPLAB": null,
            "TER_FCHTERCONT": null,
            "TER_TIPCONTRA": "",
            "CTR_NOMBRE_1": "",
            "NRO_TARVISIO": "",
            "NRO_TARVISIO1": "",
            "PAI_PK": 0,
            "PAI_NAC": 170,
            "PAIS_CODIGO": "",
            "TER_AUTTRATDATOS": "",
            "TER_CCNASESOR": 0,
            "CIIU_CODIGO_2": "",
            "CIIU_NOMBRE": "",
            "SECO_CODIGO_2": "",
            "SECO_NOMBRE_1": "",
            "TER_TOTEXCED": 0,
            "TER_DIGITOVERIF": "",
            "VALORCOND": 0,
            "TEL_CONY": "",
            "EMAIL_CONY": "",
            "NIVEL_EST_CONY": "",
            "ACTIVIDAD_CONY": "",
            "TER_SINANLUCR": "",
            "TER_SIGLA": "",
            "TIENSAL_CCODIGO": 0,
            "TER_SOCIO_S_N": "S",
            "TER_TELEFONOLAB": "",
            "CIU_CODIGOLAB": "",
            "TER_DIRECCIONLAB": "",
            "COD_CIIU_1": "",
            "CIIU_NOMBRE_1": "",
            "TER_TOTCOSTOP": 0,
            "ESTRATO_CONY": "",
            "TER_RAZONSOCIAL": "",
            "CLI_FCHINGRESOCIA": null,
            "TER_NOMCOMPLETO": ""
        }
    ]'
]
}
```

Expected:
A valid JSON. I don't know if there are more steps, I'm trying to use that code on Django. Its shows only a complete string.

Comment: Looks like you need to loop through `result[*]` and JSON parse each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sure `.json()` will do the job correctly if the server is really sending a `json` response. But it seems `Results` inside is really a `json` too.

So what you could do, if you are not the one developing the server side is:

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('http://codehere.com', auth=('user', 'pass'), content_type='application/json')
if response.status_code == 200:
    resp = response.json()
    if 'result' in resp:
        result = json.loads(resp['result'])
    else:
        print('Something is wrong with result')
        print(resp)
else:
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.content)
```

So now you can handle `result` as you please.

Comment: Sorry, it was really `r['result']` instead of `r['results']`

Answer (score 0):

Both printouts show slightly different representations of the same value.
This value is a dictionary with a single key, `'result'`, whose value
appears to be a string containing the representation of a Python list containing a single dictionary. Appearances, however, can be deceptive.

This would seem to suggest that the server is behaving in what we might call a suboptimal way. If you have any control over it that would be the logical place to fix this situation.

The content is, in essence, so badly mangled by multiple rounds of string
and/or JSON encoding that I'm not sure it's possible to easily fix this client-side.